# Parallel program wont make

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, openmp

I have moved a parallel program that was working and built in visual studio. I'm using c++
and compiling on the intel compiler. I have to move the project to a linux machine and run it. So I made the following make file.

```
parallel: main.o Node.o
    icpc -o parallel main.o Node.o

main.o: main.cpp
    icpc -c $(CONFIG) main.cpp

Node.o: Node.cpp
    icpc -c $(CONFIG) Node.cpp

clean:
    rm -f parallel *.o core core.*

CONFIG  = -openmp
```

but get this output. I can't figure out why it's not recognizing when it works on windows.

```
main.cpp:(.text+0x4e): undefined reference to `__kmpc_begin'
main.cpp:(.text+0xa2): undefined reference to `__kmpc_global_thread_num'
main.cpp:(.text+0xb2): undefined reference to `__kmpc_ok_to_fork'
main.cpp:(.text+0xc9): undefined reference to `__kmpc_fork_call'
main.cpp:(.text+0xdb): undefined reference to `__kmpc_serialized_parallel'
main.cpp:(.text+0xfa): undefined reference to `__kmpc_end_serialized_parallel'
main.cpp:(.text+0x106): undefined reference to `__kmpc_ok_to_fork'
""                  ""                         '""             """
```

Although I don't think it's necessary here is my project.

http://bitbucket.org/pumphouse/disjoint-sets-serial-parallel

Comment: have you tried the obvious (google & manual) ?

Comment: yes. I have tried to search for the answer this is day 2.

Comment: Have you tried: http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/showthread.php?t=64701 (first link on Google when searching)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not linking with `-openmp`; change your second line to

```
 icpc $(CONFIG) -o parallel main.o Node.o
```

Comment: I love you I'm going to try this right now. I'll up-vote your history if this works.

Comment: @Pumphouse: if you used Google, this was the first hit.